# Dailymotion api stop video

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am using their api: [dailmotion api](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/player.html)

How do I stop the video from downloading?

I know I can use pause, but this will continue to use bandwidth, I want to stop it and later load new video on demand.

Answer (score 1):

You basically can't control that behavior from the player API. Once the video
starts (either when the user clicks plays or if autoplay is enabled), the player
will start to download the video stream and will handle how it's downloaded.